# IndexError when integrating the solution of an ODE solved with ODEint

Tags: python, scipy, index-error, quad

I used `odeint` to solve a coupled differential equation in terms of v(t) and u(t).

```py
f = odeint(ODEs, f0, t)
    
v = f[:,0]    
u = f[:,1]
```

I want to get x, which is the integral of v(t), so I have this code that uses `scipy.integrate.quad`:

```py
x = lambda t: f[t,0]

delta_x=quad(x, 0,1)
print(delta_x)
```

When I run this, I get

```py
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

and my Jupyter Notebook highlights f[t,0]. Why is there an index error if the function is defined everywhere within the bounds of integration? How can I solve the error or get the integral via another method?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint, quad 

def ODEs(f,t):
    v = f[0]
    u = f[1]
    
    dvdt = u-v
    dudt = (v-u)/3
    
    return [dvdt, dudt]

f0 = [0.3, 0.2]

t = np.linspace(0,4,10000)
f = odeint(ODEs, f0, t)
v = f[:,0]    
u = f[:,1]  

x = lambda t: f[t,0]

delta_x=quad(x, 0,1)
print(delta_x)
```

Comment: You might consider providing a [mre] to make the question easier to investigate.

Comment: `f[t,0]` is an indexing operation.  Did you mean `f(t,0)`?

Comment: Should be fine, as long as `t` is really the index of the result element according to the initially given array of times `t`. Unfortunately, we don't have a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: `quad` will pass a float of its choice between the integration limits to function `x`.  Clearly that fractional float can't be an index!  what is `f[t,0]` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `quad` will evaluate a *function* at various points and compute the integral that way. Since you have discrete values from `odeint`, you cannot use `quad`. Instead, you can use `np.trapz` to perform the integration using the trapezoid rule from the discrete results.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def ODEs(f,t):
    v, u = f
    dvdt = u - v
    dudt = -dvdt/3
    
    return [dvdt, dudt]

f0 = [0.3, 0.2]

# changed t to the range you want the later integral over
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
f = odeint(ODEs, f0, t)
v, u = f.T

integral = np.trapz(v, t)
print(integral) # 0.266422665699249
```

Alternatively, you can use [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) with `dense_output=True`. The ODE integration result will then have a `sol` attribute which is a function that can be evaluated. This can then be used for `quad`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp, quad

# Note solve_ivp by default expect 't' to be first
def ODEs(t, f):
    v, u = f
    dvdt = u - v
    dudt = -dvdt/3
    
    return [dvdt, dudt]

f0 = [0.3, 0.2]

t_span = [0, 4]
f = solve_ivp(ODEs, t_span, f0, dense_output=True)
integral = quad(lambda t: f.sol(t)[0], 0, 1)
# the first term is the integral result and the second is the error
print(integral)  # (0.2663479453362735, 4.315387022498807e-09)
```